# Sending file name with PUT request in PHP using Rest Architecture

Tags: php, curl

How can I send the filename to an apache server if I'm using curl with

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
```

One solution was to send the filename using the URL. 
- there are several problem with this
- the biggest problem is the url can be invalid containing white spaces for example so I can't validate in anyway the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn11re189.html)

> CURLOPT_PUT (boolean) If true, sets
>   the cURL session to perform an HTTP
>   PUT operation. Information about the
>   file to be sent is set with
>   CURLOPT_INFILE and CURLOPT_INFILESIZE.

And if you mean the resulting filename on the server, that would be

> CURLOPT_URL (string) Sets the URL of
>   the remote resource to which to
>   connect. Overrides any value given
>   directly to curl_init() .

You have to configure apache to handle PUT Requests.

Comment: Only the file content and file size is sent this way.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant by that. I'll try to explain.